# Routes not working laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes

My route is for some reason not working and i don't know why.

My button link and routes.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{url('toernooi/'. $toernooi->id . '/spelers/test')}}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Export Excel
    </a>





Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth.accepted']], function() {
    Route::get('toernooien/{id}/inschrijven', 'ToernooiController@inschrijven');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth.admin']], function() {

    Route::get('toernooien/{id}/spelers', 'ToernooiController@spelers');
    Route::get('toernooien/{id}/spelers/test', function() {
        echo "test";
    });
    Route::resource('toernooien', 'ToernooiController');
    Route::get('users/{id}/updateaccepted', 'UsersController@updateaccepted');
    Route::get('users/{id}/updatenotaccepted', 'UsersController@updatenotaccepted');
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
    Route::get('users/{id}/destroy', 'UsersController@destroy');
    Route::resource('toernooien', 'ToernooiController');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::resource('/toernooien', 'ToernooiController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', ]]);
```

The error i'm getting:
[image]

I have tried putting the route in more places in the routes.php.

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route is toernooien and link is toernooi.

They must be the same

Comment: oh my god totally didn't see that i'm stupid thanks.